# Row, counting columns in another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: one with users and one with cities they live in. I need to need to make a field which will count people in city. For example J. registered on a website and have chosen a NYC as a city he lives in. In first table with users I have a row with his name, and city and in the second table I see that I have 1 man, lives in NYC. How can I do it? I use Sequel Pro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.city, COUNT(*)
  FROM city AS c
  JOIN user as u on u.userId = c.userId
  GROUP BY c.city
```